# react re render component based on api fetch

Tags: reactjs

I am building a single-page website, now I am fetching data from a movies API with different genres, and I do it on componentDidMount(), the first time its work and I get the data(movies) the without refreshing
the problem is that the component is not re-render when I switch to another genre(the movies are still the same), only when refreshing its changes to another genre movies, is there a way to so without refreshing? 
and someone can please explain to me how and when to use componentDidUpdate()?

```
Search.js:

const genresId = {
    Action: '28',
    Animation: '16',
    Comedy: '35',
    Adventure: '12'
}



export class Search extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            genre: "",
            title: this.props.match.params.genre
        }
        this.checkGenre = this.checkGenre.bind(this);
    }

    checkGenre() {
        const whichGenre = this.props.match.params.genre;
        let temp;
        if (whichGenre === 'action') {
            this.setState({genre: genresId.Action});
            temp = genresId.Action;
        } else if (whichGenre === 'animation') {
            this.setState({genre: genresId.Animation})
            temp = genresId.Animation;
        } else if (whichGenre === 'comedy') {
            this.setState({genre: genresId.Comedy})
            temp = genresId.Comedy;
        } else if (whichGenre === 'adventure') {
            this.setState({genre: genresId.Adventure})
            temp = genresId.Adventure;
        }
        return temp
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Search">
                <div className="Search-header"></div>

                <div className="Search-main">
                    <h1 className="Search-title">{this.state.title} Movies</h1>
                    <Container>
                        <SearchResult checkGenre={this.checkGenre} genreId={this.state.genre}/>
                    </Container>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

SearchResult.js: 
export class SearchResult extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            moviesArray: [],
            page: 1,
            isLoading: true
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        let urlWithParams = `${baseUrl}&page=${this.state.page}&with_genres=${this.props.checkGenre()}`
        const response = await axios.get(urlWithParams)
        this.setState({moviesArray: response.data.results, isLoading: false})
        console.log(this.state.moviesArray)

    }


    // async componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    //     if (prevProps.genre !== this.props.genre) {
    //         // ...
    //     }
    // }

    checkIfDataAvailable() {
        if (!this.state.isLoading) {
            return (
                <Row>
                    {this.state.moviesArray.map(movie =>
                         <Col key={movie.id}  sm="6" md="4" lg="3">
                         <SearchItem
                         id={movie.id}
                         title={movie.title}
                         src={`${baseImgUrl}/${movie.poster_path}`}
                         releaseDate={movie.release_date}
                         rating={movie.vote_average}
                         />
                     </Col>        
                    )}
                </Row>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <div className="spinner-border" role="status">
                    {console.log('Is Loading....')}
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="SearchResult">
                {this.checkIfDataAvailable()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount` doesn't refire on reactive updates. You will want to do your fetch in [`componentdidupdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) instead. You probably want to check whether the genre has changed before fetching, in case there are other reactive changes that can cause an update. Something like this:

```
async componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.genre !== prevProps.genre) {
    let urlWithParams = `${baseUrl}&page=${this.state.page}&with_genres=${this.props.genre}`
    const response = await axios.get(urlWithParams)
    this.setState({moviesArray: response.data.results, isLoading: false})
    console.log(this.state.moviesArray)
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe because I'm using route params ?

Comment: You are not using `this.prop.genre` anywhere in the code that fetches the data. I think that's the issue.

Comment: I only use this.prop.genre in those 2 files. I really don't see what I am doing wrong (still new to react). one more question, what do you think about checkGenre() function ? how can I refactor it?

Comment: I've made a change to the code in my post that I think makes sense (use `props.genre` directly, not call a function in the parent). Can you try with this? Another question: where do you set the genre?

Comment: still not working. I set the genre on the Search.js file. I think i have a problem with the checkGenre() function. if I am using  this.state.genre its not working, the genre state is empty  , this is why i am using the temp varibale  cause setState is async

Comment: Someone can help ?

Comment: Can someone help ??